# Leaflet map not displaying external GeoJSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geojson

Leaflet Map not Visible ....
What I am trying to do is creating a map and add external GeoJSON file I already created through QGIS app using SPH file from http://naturalearthdata.com
somehow my map is not visible there i also tried to use mapbox and google API key with leaflet library and sill having same issue 
anyone knows the solution ?? 
I couldn't add my GeoJSON file in here because it's a huge file

---

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="biewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>GeoJSON</title>
    <!-- leflet links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- <script src="CA_Bulletin_118_Groundwater_Basins.geojson"></script> -->
    <script src="test.geojson"></script>                            
    <!-- script file -->
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

My script.js file:

```
//creating a new map
 var map = new L.Map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

//create a new Geojason layer and set it up to basins var ....
// var test;
var test = L.tileLayer('basins');
var basinslayer = L.geoJson(basins).addTo(map);
```

---

And here is my CSS file:

```
/*General CSS */
html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#map {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The code you currently share looks fine. But is assumes that your `.geojson` file is actually a normal JS file where you define your `basins` variable in global scope. The URL template for your `test` tile layer is also strange, although you probably just simplified it for the sake of sharing here. If you are still stuck, you should probably share a sample of your GeoJSON file content.

Comment: Is the map not displaying at all, or is it that the geoJSON layer doesn't appear? If there's no map, it might be worth inspecting the elements on the page in developer tools to see how your container sizing is working out.

Comment: Thanks for replying @ghybs
I saved my file as GeoJSON file and I gave it var called test
first it was saying var undefined then i got this issue fixed now i don't have any error it's just shows a gray background there is no map layer 

then I did some research i add this code to my script.js file and worked fine now i have a map.
Now I am trying to add my external file which is GeoJSON file 
Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for replying @peeebeee 
I saved my file as GeoJSON file and I gave it var called test first it was saying var undefined then i got this issue fixed now i don't have any error it's just shows a gray background there is no map layer then I did some research i add this code to my script.js file and worked fine now i have a map. Now I am trying to add my external file which is GeoJSON file Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Here is my script file 
_______________________________________________
//creating a new map
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
   attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributor',    
   //other attributes.
}).addTo(map);

Comment: Please update your main post with your modifications for more clarity

Comment: I posted all my files here with GeoJSON, sorry it was the only way i could think about I tried to use inline text editor and all of them didn't upload my GeoJSON file code.
https://plus.google.com/u/0/107440761679594547487/posts/cEvzv2m6mYs

Comment: OK, so you weren't loading a tile layer - now you are. You could post an answer yourself to help someone who comes along later.

Comment: @peeebeee No, I didn't solve it yet, I am saying I used another way to add link and it showed my map
Now, I am trying to add ecternal GeoJSON file and show it on the map

Answer (score 0):

I'm also importing a geojson file to generate the points on my map. I used the [$.getJSON from jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to import the geojson file, load the data, and create the points.

If you want to try this method, you have to add jQuery in the head of your html, like this (also [found here for the latest cdn](https://code.jquery.com/)):

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My $.getJSON looks like this:

```
var getjson = $.getJSON("map-v2.geojson",function(data){
  var bev = L.geoJson(data,{
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
      var marker = L.marker(latlng);
      marker.bindPopup('<p align=center>' + '<strong>Title: </strong>' + feature.properties.Title + '<strong>Date: </strong>' + feature.properties.Date + '<br/>' + '<strong>Creator: </strong>' + feature.properties.Creator);
      return marker;
    }
  });
  bev.addTo(map);
});
```

First, I set a variable that calls [$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), which takes a few arguments, the first one is the name of the geoJSON file in quotes, and the second is function(data) which acts to say we are going to use the data found in this file. The second line I assign my variable bev to invoke the L.geoJson function, passing the argument data (which will use the data from the geoJSON file). Then I point to a new layer using pointToLayer and assigning it the value of the function(feature,latlng). feature allows me to name certain properties from my geoJSON file to display in the popups, latlng extracts the coordinates from the geoJSON file to generate the locations for the markers(latlng is mandatory). I then assign another variable called marker, and here's where you generate your markers on your map, simply by using L.marker(latlng). After that, the marker.bindPopup binds all the content I want to display on popups from the properties data I have in each of my points in the geoJson file. Here's an example of my geoJSON:

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -122.714055,
          38.440429
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Title": "Santa Rosa. Sonoma County. California. 1885.",
        "Date": "1885",
        "Creator": "W.W. Elliot & Co., lithographer."
      }
    },
```

I then return the marker, add the variable bev to the map, and there they are!

*I'm not an expert on JavaScript or Leaflet, so if my wording is off, I will gladly make edits to make it clearer.